# Can you use two (or more) semicolons with two (or more) conjunctive adverbs?

Tags: conjunctions, semicolons, independent-clauses

I am confident that I know how to use semicolons, and I would like to use them more often; but, there is one thing with the semicolon that I cannot find an answer on: Can you use two (or more) semicolons before two (or more) conjunctive adverbs?

Let me create a random sentence as an example:

> Cats are considered one of the cutest animals; in addition, they help keep mice out of your house; however, when they are not hunting, they sit around all day cleaning themselves and sleeping.

(Forgive my random sentence, I just came up with it on a whim.)

Essentially, would "***C1**; in addition, **C2**; however, **C3**.*" be an appropriate use of semicolons, or is there a "limit" to how many you can or should use?

Comment: I would not have used a semicolon in your opening sentence.

Comment: Commas can be used to indicate parenthesis but semicolons, so far as I know, are not. Also you don't need the comma after 'in addition' so you could have used commas to form the parenthesis. Having said that a full stop before 'however' would have been much clearer and formed a better paragraph.

Comment: 'I am confident that I know how to use semicolons, and I would like to use them more often. But there is one aspect about the use of the semicolon that I cannot find an answer on: can you use two (or more) semicolons before two (or more) conjunctive adverbs in the same sentence?' // Using more than a single colon or a single semicolon in a sentence (other than in complex lists / times etc) is usually regarded as poor style. And using even one should be done with care: independent clauses are often better set off as independent sentences.